# What is the default size unit of unrar?

Tags: compression, unrar

I have rar files but want to see the uncompressed size without unraring them.
I am using unrar through the command line.

I am using unrar v  which lists:

```
Attributes      Size    Packed Ratio    Date    Time   Checksum  Name
----------- ---------  -------- ----- ---------- -----  --------  ----
          32837413376 5881611972  17%                              1711
```

I am wondering what that size is? Bytes? MB? GB? i tried conversions. I unpacked this one personally and the size is 92 Gigs. I check in the command line by using dn -ch ./* as well as the windows file explorer properties.

Im hoping the ration does not have a play in this factor

Answer (score 0):

## TLdr;

Answer is the **unpacked size in bytes**.

### Explanation

I have been looking for an answer since a while. I believe, I just found the answer. It looks kind of dumb, but mentioning in case somebody else miss the puck. Mentioning the units used would have prevented this.

My conclusion is the **unpacked size in bytes**.

Why I believe so? Using Winrar on Windows, you can right click on the `.rar` archive and click on view file.

You will then see:
[image: Winrar programme interface on Windows]

- The name of the archive,
- its size (For me it is the same value, I get from running `unrar l` (gives the same as `unrar v`, which show the difference between the file packed and unpacked and the relevant ratio),
- packed, which match the size of the file I got from looking at the `properties`
- Type, Modified, etc. which are not relevant elements to this question.

To verify the whole thing, I went back to Linux, and extracted the files I have the same amount in bytes as disclosed by the `unrar` command. What do you get?